# How to specify an URL in .env file of Gatsby app?

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, dotenv

Just in case, I'd like to know against Gatsby app, in case its settings differ from other node based apps.

I want to refactor `gatsby-config.js` by moving `http://localhost:1337` to `.env`.

From

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
    options: {
      apiURL: `http://localhost:1337`,
    },
  },
]
```

To

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
    options: {
      apiURL: process.env.STRAPI,
    },
  },
]
```

and `.env` as follows didn't work for me:

`STRAPI=$(http://localhost:1337)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in the root of your project named `.env.development` and `.env.production`. There, create your variable, just:

```
STRAPI= "http://localhost:1337"
```

In your `gatsby-config.js` add the following snippet (above module exportation):

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Finally, leave the configuration just with:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
    options: {
      apiURL: process.env.STRAPI,
    },
  },
]
```

By default, Gatsby will take the `.env.development` or `.env.production` when running `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` respectively, allowing you to pass the environment variables to the server files (`gatsby-config.js`, etc).